# When I run a python program it closes instantly

Tags: python, pyautogui

I wrote a really simple script that locates the 'Accept_Button' (which is a button) and then makes the mouse move to it:

```
import pyautogui
x, y =  pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Accept_Button.png')
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
```

The problem is that the button is not always on screen (it only appears from time to time) and if the program does not find it instantly it will instantly close.The only fix for this is when I open the program with IDLE and then manually click on run or F5, but this way is not useful. 
Thank you in advance!

Edit:

```
 import time
  import pyautogui

  while True:
      x, y =  pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Accept_Button.png')
      pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
```

This is the new script, which is working fine, I just have no idea how to create a loop to when there is no button on screen and the program needs to wait for it to appear.

Comment: After python program finished executing it is suppose to close.

Comment: i think the problem is that the scripts runs and as you dont have any more things to do it closes, and apparently it does nothing. But it does it and close very fast.

Comment: try just adding an `input()` at the end just to test

Comment: You could run it in a loop so that it repeatedly operates and will continually search the screen for the button.

Comment: Ivan - I have tried and it does not work it still closes which I don't understand why.

Comment: Professor Joykill could you tell me how to do that I am new to programing and don't know how to do so, thans!

Comment: if you're new to programming, you shouldn't try making guis.  start with a hello world, then learn conditionals and looping

Comment: I know those basics just didn't got to loops yet. And with this module it is quite easy to make guis  I just have no idea how to make a loop on this case.

Comment: put it inside a `while True` loop maybe with a `time.sleep(2)` at the end

Comment: @Ivan That will just wait on `input()` it will not rerun the locate command. It does not do any good.

Comment: *A wild [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html) appears!* Please read (and understand) this first, as loops are one of the most basic concepts of programming. It's like learning basic arithmetic operations - you will need them for *everything* else later on.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want a simple repeating loop for your program, here is one that runs and then delays for a couple of seconds at the end

```
import time
import pyautogui

while True
    x, y =  pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Accept_Button.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
    time.sleep(seconds you want it to sleep)
```

This will make the image location program continously run until you manually cancel it. The `time.sleep()` method at the bottom means that there will be a delay between detection attempts.

Comment: The `locateCenterOnScreen()` function will return `None` when it fails, so I think it would be better to loop (with the delay) until that's not the case, then do the `movetTo()`. The [documentation](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) also says it returns a "4-integer tuple: (left, top, width, height)", you would need to find the center of that to pass to `moveTo()`.

Comment: You have made the program not close itself when it actually finds the button, which is fine, however, what I need is the loop to continue when the image is NOT on screen and therefore keep looping till there is the 'Accept_Button.png'